# Changing jQuery UI Button size?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-button

I've been using the jQuery UI button all over my page, however I haven't found a way around what seems to be a simple problem. I want some of my buttons to be smaller than the other, this should be as simple as setting the CSS of the button text to something like, `font: .8em;` However jQuery UI takes your DOM element and wraps it:

```
<button class="ui-button ui-button-text-only ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all">
   <span class="ui-button-text">Button Label</span>
</button>
```

So if I have a `<button class="small-button">Small button!</button>` jQuery will place the text in a child span. Any font size given to the `small-button` class will be ignored.

There's got to be a way around this without hacking at how jQuery makes its buttons. Any ideas?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If it's styling `ui-button-text` with `font-size` directly, you can override it at a higher level by applying !important. Such as:

```
.small-button {
   font-size: .8em !important;
}
```

EDIT: try setting a CSS style directly on `.ui-button-text` to inherit:

```
.ui-button-text {
   font-size: inherit !important;
}
```

This should also make the !important on the `.small-button` irrelevant.

Comment: This did not work unfortunately. The small-button class is hanging off the button element and not overwriting the inner span.

Comment: Have a look at my edit, that might help you out. It would be beneficial to see your full example in action (with all the CSS applied to it). Im going to gather that you're probably using a jQuery UI CSS file for the button, this could be solved by modifying that CSS directly to get your desired needs.

Answer (score 14):

This helped decrease the height of the button for me (Smoothness theme default is line-height of 1.4):

```
.ui-button .ui-button-text
{
 line-height: 1.0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is what I use in my websites to setup the font-sizes so that my button sizes are the same as on the [jQuery UI website](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/). This works because it's exactly how the [jQuery UI website](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) does it!

```
/* percentage to px scale (very simple)
 80% =  8px
100% = 10px
120% = 12px
140% = 14px
180% = 18px
240% = 24px
260% = 26px
*/

body
{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:10px;
}
```

By setting the font-size properties like that for the body element, setting the font-size for everything else becomes trivial as 100% = 10px.

Just watch out for the cascading effect when using percentages - a child element's 100% will be equal to the parent element's font-size.

Answer (score 5):

You can create different sized buttons by modifying the padding of the span element that is contained within the markup jQuery generates, as Tim suggests.

This markup/JavaScript...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").button();
});

<button id="some-id" class="some-class">Some Button</button>
```

Results in this transformed markup...

```
<button class="some-class ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all 
          ui-button-text-only" id="some-id" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
<span class="ui-button-text">some button</span>
</button>
```

Which most certainly includes the `id` and `class` tags which were originally supplied.  You can modify the size of your buttons by adding more padding to the `span.ui-button-text` element.

Like So..

```
button#some-id .ui-button-text {
    /* padding values here to your liking */
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just change the button font-size ;).

```
<asp:Button ID="btn2" runat="server" Text="Button" style="font-size:10px" />
```

Now add a jquery script to the button

```
   <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('input:submit, #btn2').button();
        });
    </script>
```

Good Luck. ;)

Comment: When using unique ID of element, the `input:submit` selector is just unneeded overhead..

Answer (score 3):

I used a combination of two suggestions above. It's pretty easy to tweak the UI just the way I like it.

To page's stylesheet add:

```
.ui-button .ui-button-text
{
   padding: 0px 11px 0px 21px !important;
   font-size: .72em !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I did this and it works fine.

```
$( "button" ).button("font-size", "0.8em");
```

Comment: I don't think that will work. I tried it with jQuery 1.11.2 and it failed. This should be the correct way:                           $( "button" ).button().css( "font-size", "0.8em" ) ;

Answer (score 0):

My solution needed to work across the new menu items as well

The first to select the matching elements for both menu and button

```
.menu>.ui-button-icon-only,
.ui-button{
font-size:0.8em !important;
}
```

And the second as above to force inheiritance

```
.ui-button-text {
 font-size: inherit !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery at runtime, without modifying CSS.  This gives you a lot more flexibility.

```
$(function() {
  $("input[type=button]").css("font-size", "0.8em");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`<input type="submit" value="Mostrar imágenes">`

and my css:

```
input[type="submit"] {
color: #000;
border: 0 none;
cursor: pointer;
height: 30px;
width: 150px; }
```