# jQuery Ui button font-size

Tags: css, jquery-ui, primefaces, font-size

I've recently added Primefaces to my WEb app in order to use it's dataTable UI. So I decided to go and up the font size of the dataTable to 12px instead of the default 10px it comes with. so I added this to my Css:

```
.ui-widget,         .ui-widget .ui-widget {                
font-size: 12px !important;          
}
```

Anyway, I was also using a button with the `styleclass="button"` which comes from the jquery.ui and now it's affected that style as well to a 12px font, but I wanted to keep the button font to 10px.

Is there a way to fix the font size for just the button? or do I have to add something to the above code to make it just affect the dataTable?

The button looks like this:

```
<h:commandButton id="auditButton" action="#{auditBB.actionSearch}" styleClass="button"  value="Search"></h:commandButton>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It took me a while to find it, but I found [this Stack Overflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3380580/changing-jquery-ui-button-size) and it has *a few* answers on it. the one I used to solve my issue was to add the following code into my Css.

```
.ui-button,  .ui-button-text .ui-button{  
font-size: 10px !important; 
}
```

That took care of it, Thanksfor reading. I hope this helps somebody. =)